# Second derivative dot product

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, multilinear-algebra

I was wondering whether I am correct that the second derivative of the dot product is this:

Let $f:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle$
Then we have $f'(x_1,x_2) (h_1,h_2)= f(x_1,h_2) + f(h_1,x_2)$
and consequently I woul say $f''(x_1,x_2)[(w_1,w_2),(w_3,w_4)]= f(w_3,w_2)+f(w_1,w_4)$. WHat makes me thinking that this is wrong is, that it does no longer depend on $(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: The inner product is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear, thus its second derivative is constant (and its third derivative is $0$).

Comment: perfect, this really explains it. thank you